# upload Image.png through parse in swift in UItableView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

i would like to upload image through parse server in my app ( in UITableView) , i currently write this code but it doesn't work, i mean, it works well to upload songs,but it doesn't upload Picture, any suggestion ?

```
 import UIKit
    import Parse

    import Bolts
    import AVFoundation
    import AVKit


public var AudioPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var SelectedSongNumber = Int()


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{


var iDArray = [String]()
var NameArray = [String]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery (className: "Songs")
    ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({

         (objectsArray: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]


        NSLog("\(objectIDs)")



        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{

    self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
        self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("SongName") as! String)

            self.tableView.reloadData()


            }
   })

}

        func grabSong(){

            var SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
            SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:  {


                (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

                if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url{

                    AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
                    AudioPlayer.play()

      }

    })


}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return iDArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
    grabSong()

}



}
```

Comment: Do you mean download? Where exactly is the issue in your code, you talk about `pictures` but in the code it is `songs`?

Comment: No, actually i want to upload a picture instead of Song through the Parse, for example, i want to create Gallery for my App and i want to always upload photo through the parse...

Comment: I don't see any code there to upload, are you asking how to do it or are you asking what is wrong with your code?